# CreateInstance em classe Tipada

Tags: c#

Minha intenção é recuperar a minha **Entidade** e o **Repositorio** respectivo da mesma através de uma *string* passada para o método.

Com isso eu vou fazer com que ele consiga executar o `GetAll()` do meu repositório genérico independente da classe que foi passada, mas preciso instanciar a mesma.

Até agora o código está assim, porém da uma mensagem de referência nula na linha:

```
var entidades = (repository as RepositoryBase<EntityBase>).GetByFilter("1=1 AND " + filter);
```

Método:

```
public static MvcHtmlString SearchComboBox(string nameIdKey, object value, string controller, string tableName, string descriptionField, string filter = "1=1",  bool obrigatorio = false)
        {
        string options = string.Empty;

            Type type = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .ToList()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.FullName.IndexOf("LaioMVC.Core") > -1)
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(x => x.Name.ToUpper() == tableName.ToUpper())
                .Single();

            EntityBase entity = null;

            if (type != null)
            {
                entity = (EntityBase)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

                Type typeRep = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .ToList()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.FullName.IndexOf("LaioMVC.Data") > -1)
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(x => x.Name == tableName + "Repository")
                .Single();

                if (typeRep != null)
                {
                    var repository = Activator.CreateInstance(typeRep);

                    var entidades = (repository as RepositoryBase<EntityBase>).GetByFilter("1=1 AND " + filter);

                    for (int i = 0; i < entidades.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        Type campoKey = entity.GetType();
                        PropertyInfo info = campoKey.GetProperty(nameIdKey);

                        Type campoDescricao = entity.GetType();
                        PropertyInfo infoDesc = campoKey.GetProperty(nameIdKey);

                        options += Environment.NewLine;
                        options += string.Format("<option value='{0}'> {1} </option>", info.ToString(), infoDesc.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(options);
        }
```

Repositorio:

```
using Dapper;
using LaioMVC.Core;
using LaioMVC.Core.Attributes;
using LaioMVC.Core.Models;
using LaioMVC.Core.ViewModels;
using LaioMVC.Data.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LaioMVC.Data.Repositorios
{
    public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepositoryBase<T>
            where T : EntityBase
    {
            public List<T> GetAll()
        {
            var query = $"select * from {typeof(T).Name} ";

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Constants.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                return connection.Query<T>(query).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EntityBase:

```
namespace LaioMVC.Core.Models
{
    public class EntityBase 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Lembrando que todas as entidades herdam de `EntityBase`.

Será que alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Sinceridade, só uma dica, você está complicando um item que pode ser simplesmente enviar valores para esse método.

Comment: É porque eu vou passar os valores para o método através da minha View usando Razor. Então eu posso usar para montar o código HTML de qualquer entidade, porisso teria que ser algo genérico

Comment: Você está colocando uma responsabilidade na sua `View` desnecessária, porque, quem manda informação é o seu `Controller` ... Eu não entendi o que deseja montar, pelo visto é um `Select` que se for já existe as classes para fazer isso. Isso gera um encapsulamento e deve prestar atenção nisso.

Comment: Minha intenção é montar um `Select` com os dados da entidade que eu buscar no banco,  passando para meu componente personalizado (SearchComboBox()) através dos parametros (strings) quais dados no banco terei que buscar. Depois com os parametros eu quero instanciar a classe passada através da string e retornar o HTML do combobox com os `options` montados.

Comment: Sim, mas, o seu `SearchComboBox()` tem código de banco e não poderia, ele deveria ter somente dados! Bom eu penso assim, talvez pra você seja diferente.

Comment: De qualquer forma seria só migrar o código para algum serviço não? Porém mesmo assim precisaria que a lógica funcionasse :/